# Learning Webpack: how to include library in webpack and use in browser

Tags: javascript, webpack

I thought this question must have been asked many times but I could not find a suitable answer. Maybe its because I do not know all the buzzwords correctly...

So, I tried to use bundling for a new project (to keep up to date) and had a small test.
I want to use tailwindcss, and a datepicker (js-datepicker: https://github.com/qodesmith/datepicker).

src/index.js:

```
import './styles.css'
import datepicker from 'js-datepicker'
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {importLoaders: 1}
                    },
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ]
}
```

and now I want to use the date picker in my browser, so I included the generated 'bundle.js' into my HTML

but

```
const picker = datepicker('#someid')
```

generated an error:
"ReferenceError: datepicker is not defined"

What is the magic trick I am missing? If I look at the generated bundle.js, I can see all the tailwind styles and the datepicker-code...

Answer (score 1):

You can add `datepicker` to `window`, and then you can use it in browser.

In your `index.js` file

```js
import './styles.css'
import datepicker from 'js-datepicker'

// Add datepicker to window object
window.datepicker = datepicker;
```

Comment: Ok, yes. That could be a solution. But I thought one of the advantages is not to pollute the windows namepace?

Comment: In browser, all global variables  belong to the window object. There is no way to define a global variable and not add it to window.

Comment: Other possibiliy is to write a wrapper (e.g. app.js) that includes the datepicker ans other used libraries and is global?